# Progress bar Visibility

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a very simple scenario: I have to make my progress bar *invisible* at the starting, but on the button click, have to make it *visible* so that the tasks which I am running in the background will be done and till then my progress bar will run.

I am using a very simple way. I have put the progress bar in XML, then simply at the `onCreate` method of the activity, first making it invisible by `mProgress.setVisibility(4)` and then when I am clicking my button trying to make this *visible* again.

But unfortunately its not working! Anyone please reply why its not doing this.

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mProgress.setVisibility(4);

btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    strpatientid = txtpatientid.getText().toString();

    if (strpatientid.length() == 0) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Enter the Patient ID",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
    }
    else {
      mProgress.setEnabled(false);
      mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      setProgressBarVisibility(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean its not working? paste your full code

Comment: so whats the current behaviour? what does it do when you click the button?

Comment: the progress bar remains invisible in all the cases

Comment: even after you write something in txtpatientid?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
mProgress=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    strpatientid = txtpatientid.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strpatientid)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the Patient ID",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return;
    }

    else{
        //mProgress.setEnabled(false);   //you dont need this
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setProgressBarVisibility(true);
    }
}
```